# The rate of change of a certain population is proportional to the square root of its size. Model this situation with a differential equation.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, mathematical-modeling

The rate of change of a certain population is proportional to the square root of its size. Model this situation with a differential equation.

The solution is said to be $\dfrac{dP}{dt} = k\sqrt{P}$, where $k > 0$ is the proportionality constant.

Since the problem statement says **rate of change** instead of rate of increase, isn't it true that $k$ can be both positive and negative rather than just positive?

Comment: I agree that $k$ can be either positive or negative.

Comment: I would even argue that "rate of increase" can be negative. To force the rate of change to be positive, you can either say so explicitly ("the rate of change is positive") or you can imply it with other words such as, "A population is growing with a rate of change that is ... ."

Comment: The "rate" of change could also be interpreted to be the change relative to the value, $\dot P/P$ so that the ODE becomes $\dot P=k·P^{3/2}$.

Comment: This question is from the MIT course 18.03SC https://ocw.mit.edu/courses/mathematics/18-03sc-differential-equations-fall-2011/unit-i-first-order-differential-equations/basic-de-and-separable-equations/MIT18_03SCF11_ps1_s1q.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It certainly could be negative. The person who wrote the solution probably mean $|k| > 0$ instead, because if $ k = 0 $, then there is no growth at all. But a negative k is perfectly valid.